# UITextFieldInstance.text class is different in iOS 10.3.x between DEBUG and RELEASE

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Seems marked text in UITextField will cause a bug only occurs in iOS 10.3.x Release build. And I found `[UITextFieldInstance.text class]` is different in different situations.

**iOS 10.3.x**

DEBUG: __NSCFString

RELEASE: NSTaggedPointerString

**other version**

always __NSCFString

**Some of my code here:**

```
- (void)changeTitle:(id)sender {
    UITextField* textField = sender;
    NSString* passStr;
    __block NSUInteger count = 0;
    __block NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length);
    [textField.text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        unichar uc;
        [substring getBytes:&uc maxLength:4 usedLength:NULL encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, substring.length) remainingRange:NULL];
        if (uc >= 0x2e80 && uc < 0xa000) {
            count += 2;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
        if (count == MAX_CHARACTORS) {
            range = NSMakeRange(0, substringRange.location + substringRange.length);
            *stop = YES;
        } else if (count > MAX_CHARACTORS) {
            range = NSMakeRange(0, substringRange.location);
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
    passStr = [textField.text substringWithRange:range];
    if (!textField.markedTextRange) {
        textField.text = passStr;
    }
    self.sketchViewModel.signatureTitle = passStr;
    [self updateSignatureTitle];
}
```

It is `[textField.text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { ... }]` where crashes the app.

`NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length)` will throw exception **EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS**, which means the range is out of bounds. So I guess it's because the text's class is different and which causes different behavior.

Anyone have the same problem?